# return 2 values django model methods

Tags: django, django-admin

this is a trivial example to illustrate my point

```
class A(models.Model):
  boolean_field=models.BooleanField(default=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

  def true_value(self):
    if self.boolean_field:
      return self.name
    else:
      return ''

  def false_value(self):
    if not self.boolean_field:
      return self.name
    else:
      return ''
```

In `admin.py`

```
class Aadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('true_value', 'some_other_field', 'false_value')
```

I think the database is hit twice, in the example above. Is there any way to get the values in one go and use it in list_display. Is there any way to optimise this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276509/django-admin-show-aggregate-values-from-related-model

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do not guess, profile.

Comment: Why would you think the db is hit twice? That's just not true.

Comment: @ Daniel If that is true, then no problem with the implementation. But I presume it would hit twice as there are two separate methods making calls to database.

Comment: @catherine yes it may be required for example in accounting, one is debit amount, and one credit amount, depending on the Boolean field

Comment: @paulo ;) that is true.

Comment: Just as @DanielRoseman said, it's false assumption. In change list, items on one page would be loaded as a whole and then be iterated for rendering each row. Thus for one row, `true_value()` and `false_value()` would be called upon the same item w/o hitting DB at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point which I made in my comment deserves further explanation, because it's clear you have quite a big misunderstanding about the way Django's model layer works.

Once Django has fetched an object from the database, subsequent calls to different attributes in that object do not trigger extra calls to the db. Unless you specifically ask otherwise, all attributes of a model are fetched at the same time and stored in the model instance. (The only case where an extra call would happen are if the attribute is a foreign key, but even there you can avoid that using `select_related`.)

In fact, it's not even the case there would be one call per object, because Django will fetch all the rows on the page with just one single call.

Comment: I agree, I am not proficient in the finer nuances of django, but that does not mean  misunderstanding. And thank you for removing this apprehension about optimization.